# Symfony doctrine charset issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to learn `symfony` and working by various examples. The main problem is that I don't really know how to configure `doctrine.yaml`.

I'm using `SQLSRV`

When I load `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append`
error appears:
`SQLSTATE [IMSSP, -48]: The encoding 'utf8' is not a supported encoding for the CharacterSet connection option.`

my doctrine configuration is:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_sqlsrv'
        charset: utf8
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8
            collate: utf8_general_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

also I tried default configuration:

```
 charset: utf8mb4
    default_table_options:
        charset: utf8mb4
        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: `utf8mb4` and related values are most likely specific to MySQL while you're seems to use MS SQL Server. You most likely need to refer MS SQL Server documentation for correct values for charset definition

Answer (score 2):

The character set `utf8` doesn't exist, but `UTF-8` (all caps) does. According to Microsoft's [PDO_SQLSRV documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-send-and-retrieve-utf-8-data-using-built-in-utf-8-support?view=sql-server-ver15):

> To send or retrieve UTF-8 encoded data to the server:
>
> 1. Make sure that the source or destination column is of type nchar or nvarchar.
> 2. Specify the PHP type as SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING('UTF-8') in the parameters array. Or, specify "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8" as a connection option.
>
>    When you specify a character set as part of the connection options, the driver assumes that the other connection option strings use that same character set. The server name and query strings are also assumed to use the same character set.
>
> You can pass UTF-8 or SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR to CharacterSet, but you cannot pass SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY. The default encoding is SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR.

You might want to try the following instead:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_sqlsrv'
        charset: UTF-8
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Comment: I already tried these settings but still get the same error. I use sqlsrv instead of pdo_sqlsrv btw.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I have just found the problem. The problem is not related to charset. The problem was related to misusing of environment file. env.local was active and it was set to utf8 as default. I changed the .env.local file instead of .env and problem is fixed now.