# Symfony returns utf8 encoding error althought I have updated the config

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony

My problem is that I get the following error, although I have updated the config for my Symfony project. Here is the problem:

```
An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE [IMSSP, -48]: The encoding 'utf8' is not a supported encoding for the CharacterSet connection option.
```

And this is my doctrine.yaml file:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    driver: 'sqlsrv'
    server_version: '2017'
    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    charset: 'cp1254'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

I am using MSSQL 2017 with my Symfony application and sqlsrv driver. I did not understand the reason I get the error and I will be happy if someone can find the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the problem. The problem that I was triyng to update .env file but in my local I was supposed to update .env.local. It is working now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please accept your own answer. So, the community will focus on other questions :) TY.

Answer (score 0):

First, I advise you to be careful that the DATABASE_URL environment variable doesn't override the charset you have configured. (Sometimes, there is something like this line:

```
DATABASE_URL=sqlsrv://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:32781/app?charset=utf8
```

Then, according to the [configuration reference](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineBundle/current/configuration.html), charset option is RDBMS specific, developers have to refer to the manual of their RDBMS for more information.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303328/symfony-doctrine-charset-issue) the charset utf8 doesn't exist, but the charset UTF-8.

So, try to be sure that the syntax `cp1254` is existing. (I see some things more complex like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS`, but this is perhaps collation, not charset)

IMO and according to the error message, your problem is related to my first suggestion because your charset config seems to be ignored.

If your parameter is still ignored, try to remove url parameter in your doctrine.yaml file and temporally use something without the env variables.

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:           default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname:               db_name
                host:                 localhost
                port:                 3000
                user:                 foo
                charset:              'CP1254'
```

Comment: I already tried the configuration you mentioned but still get the same error. I also use sqlsrv driver instead of pdo_sqlsrv btw.

Comment: But, your parameter is still ignore. So I guess that there is a misconfiguration call. Did you tried to totally remove the `url` parameter? I updated my answer

Comment: As I mentioned it is working right now.